# Is there a way to display poll question results in Gravity forms before submitting the form?

Tags: plugin-gravity-forms

When you have a poll on Gravity Forms, you can have a lot of questions or fields on the poll. But it's only until you hit the submit button that you'll see each field results.

Is there a way that they can click on their answer, see the result, and just submit when they finish?

Answer (score 0):

https://wordpress.org/plugins/maxicharts/

I included the input results with a shortcode in a html area, not sure if it works with that add-on but it should.

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find what you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.